# How to calculate probability based on 2 cases?

Tags: probability

I feel that this is an easy one, but I want to make sure I understand it properly.

So, let's say that I want to calculate the probability of an event B and I know that if event A happens than B's probability to happen is p1 and if event A doesn't happen than B's probability is p2.
I also know the probability of event A to happen.

So what is the probability of B to happen? How do I combine the two probabilities from the two possible outcomes of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|\bar{A})P(\bar{A})$$
... and  $P(\bar{A})=1-P(A)$.

In your example $P(B|A) =p_1$ and $P(B|\bar{A})=p_2$.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [total probability formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

---

Here is a sketch of how to re-prove it in your case:

$$B=(B\cap A)\cup (B\cap \overline A)$$ and $$(B\cap A)\cap (B\cap \overline A)=\emptyset$$ imply $$P(B)=P(B\cap A)+ P(B\cap \overline A)$$
Now use the definition of conditional probability: $$P(E\mid F)=\frac{P(E\cap F)}{P(F)}$$
which works for any $E,F$ as soon as $P(F)>0$ (so choose them well to suit yourself).

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this answer?

Comment: No idea, have my upvote

Comment: @Kenshin Thanks :) sorry again for the confusion on your question.